# Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x-[x]$. Determine those points at which $f$ has a limit, and justify your conclusions.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$[x]$ denotes the largest integer that is less than or equal to $x$.

Ok, so I can see that $f$ has a limit at every point in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, but I am having a difficult time justifying this. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By $[x]$, do you mean the *floor function*, i.e., $[x]=\max\{n:n\leq x\text{ and }n\in\mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: Hint: For any $x \not\in Z$ there is a $n\in Z$ s.t. $n < x < n+1$ which gives $f(x) = x-n$. For $x\in Z$ we have $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ since $ \lfloor x \rfloor $ is constant there.

Comment: @PierreYvesGaudreauLamarre Yes. I just updated my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$. Then, (as Winther comments) there exists an integer $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n<x<n+1$.

Now, for any $y\in(n,n+1)$,
it is clear that $f(y)=y-n$ (including $y=x$).
Fix $\epsilon>0$.
Then,
if we let
$$\delta=\min\left\{\frac{x-n}2,\frac{(n+1)-x}{2},\epsilon\right\},$$
we see that if $|y-x|<\delta$,
then
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=|(x-n)-(y-n)|,
\end{align*}
because $\delta<x-n,~(n+1)-x$ and $|y-x|<\delta$ guarantee that $y\in(n,n+1)$.
Furthermore,
$$|(x-n)-(y-n)|=|x-y|<\delta\leq\epsilon.$$
Therefore,
$f$ is continuous at $x$,
hence the limit exists at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$. It is clear for some $\delta^*$ that there is no integer in $(x-\delta^*,x+\delta^*)$. Proceed like a regular limit but consider only $\delta < \delta^*$. You may now assume $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is constant and the limit is trivial.

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if you set $\epsilon = \tfrac{1}{2}$ there is no delta that satisfies the necessary inequalities.